# How to handle logout + redirect in a centralized manner

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router, redux-toolkit

I'm performing everything which is needed for logout (async http request, localstorage + state update) within an reducer (+ `AsyncThunk`). The only thing I'm missing is to also perform the required redirect to the login page from within this "centralized context".

Here's the main code involved:

**http.service.ts**

```
// ...
const httpClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ /* ... */ });

httpClient.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async function (error) {
  if (401 === error.response.status) {
    // TODO: How to logout incl. http request, localstorage + state update & redirect?
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
// ...
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
// ...
class AuthService {
  // ...
  async logout(): Promise<void> {
    localStorage.removeItem("User");
    await httpClient.post(ApiRoutesService.postLogout());
  }
}
// ...
```

**auth.slice.ts**

```
// ...
export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  await AuthService.logout();
});
// ...
const authSlice = createSlice({
  // ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      // ...
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state, _action) => {
        state.isLoggedIn = false;
        state.id = emptyUser.id;
        state.email = emptyUser.email;
        state.fullName = emptyUser.fullName;
      });
  },
});
// ...
```

**app-header.tsx**

```
// ...
export default function AppHeader(): JSX.Element {
  // ...
  const onLogout = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(logout());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {/* ... */}
        <li>
          <Link to={RouterService.paths.login} onClick={onLogout}>
            Logout
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {/* ... */}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

## The problem

ATM there are 2 places where I'd like to perform the whole logout incl. http request, localStorage + state update **and** redirect to login page:

1. From within component `AppHeader`
2. From "401 interceptor" on every http request

Whilst all of required "actions" are already happening inside `AppHeader` I don't know who to do all this from within `http.service.ts`.

## The questions

1. How can I dispatch the `logout` action from within `http.service.ts` on 401 interception?
   In other words: How to dispatch actions from a "raw TS service" (or other "non react component files") when not having access to the `useDispatch` hook?
   I already tried directly using the store's dispatch method using `import { store } from '.../store'` + `store.dispatch(logout);` but that gave me rather hard to understand runtime errors.
2. How should I perform the router redirect from within the 401 interceptor?
   This basically comes down to the same questions as above: How to perform the redirect when not having access to the `useHistory` hook? Is there some way to "directly" access the router history?
3. In addition to the above: Should I rather perform the router redirect directly from within the logout `AsyncThunk` instead of doing it from everywhere the reducer is called (ATM `AppHeader` & the 401 interceptor)?
   If it is recommended to perform the redirect from the `AsyncThunk`: How to use the router history (same question as above...)?
4. Is all of the above "nonsense"? If so, what are actual best practices here?

## FYI

I'm quite new to the whole React ecosystem and am just learning all the concepts involved. The shown code was pretty much copy pasted & adjusted from various online resources and whilst I do understand the basics involved I only have a somewhat shallow understanding of all the details regarding redux toolkit, hooks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by combining some advice I found in other SO questions and internet resources (blogs etc.):

## Overview

- "Inject" the redux store after creation into the http service to allow it to dispatch actions (`logout` here)
- Create an explicit `ProtectedRoute` component which is used instead of the routers default `Route` for routes which need the user to be authenticated.
  This route "listens" to changes in the store and performs the redirect either if someone tries to access a protected route without ever being authenticated or if an authenticated user gets logged out during runtime (e.g. because of some expired cookie etc.).

## Implementation details

**http.service.ts**

```
const httpClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ /* ... */ });

// Creation of the interceptor is now wrapped inside a function which allows
// injection of the store
export function setupHttpInterceptor(store: AppStore): void {
  http.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async function (error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
      // Store action can now be dispatched from within the interceptor
      store.dispatch(logout());
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
}
```

**store.ts**

```
// ...
import { setupHttpInterceptor } from '../services/http.service';
// ...

export const store = configureStore({ /* ... */ });

setupHttpInterceptor(store); // Inject the store into the http service

// ...
```

**protected-route.tsx**

```
// ...

type ProtectedRouteProps = { path?: string } & RouteProps;

export function ProtectedRoute(routeProps: ProtectedRouteProps): JSX.Element {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const loginCmpState: LoginLocationState = { referrer: routeProps.path };

  // This handles the redirect and also reacts to changes to `auth` state "during runtime"
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <Route {...routeProps} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: RouterService.paths.login, state: loginCmpState }} />
  );
}
```

**app-body.tsx** (wherever routes are defined)

```
// ...
export default function AppBody(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/login'>
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <ProtectedRoute path='/user-home'>
        <UserHome />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    </Switch>
  );
}
// ...
```

## Considerations

I find it a little hacky that the store needs to inject itself into the http service as this creates a kind of coupling between those 2 which is IMHO not very clean. The http service won't work correctly if the store somehow "forgets" to do the interception...

Whilst this basically works, I'm still very open for improvement suggestions!